# How can I use GetElementsByTagName to get the innerText of the last element if there's more than one element with the same name?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML

```
<WordDefinition>
  <Word>analyses</Word>
  <Definitions>
    <Definition>
      <Word>analyses</Word>
      <Dictionary>
        <Id>wn</Id>
        <Name>WordNet (r) 2.0</Name>
      </Dictionary>
      <WordDefinition>analyses
         See {analysis}
      </WordDefinition>
    </Definition>
    <Definition>
      <Word>analyses</Word>
      <Dictionary>
        <Id>wn</Id>
        <Name>WordNet (r) 2.0</Name>
      </Dictionary>
      <WordDefinition>analysis
     n 1: an investigation of the component parts of a whole and their
          relations in making up the whole
      </WordDefinition>
    </Definition>
  </Definitions>
</WordDefinition>
```

I coded up this C# to get the innerText of the "WordDefinition" which works okay if there is just one "wordDefinition".  However if there's **one or more than one** I want to get the innerText of the last one.

```
 var doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(responseFromServer);
 var el = doc.GetElementsByTagName("WordDefinition");
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this? For this example I want to get the innerText of this:

```
  <WordDefinition>analysis
 n 1: an investigation of the component parts of a whole and their
      relations in making up the whole
  </WordDefinition>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36714360/5045688) topic. You may be interested in. Try an approach like in my answer instead of manually getting response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the VB...  Using XElement you can get the last WordDefinition like this

```
    Dim doc As XElement

    ' to load   doc = XElement.Load("path/URI here")
    ' for testing
    doc = <WordDefinition>
              <Word>analyses</Word>
              <Definitions>
                  <Definition>
                      <Word>analyses</Word>
                      <Dictionary>
                          <Id>wn</Id>
                          <Name>WordNet (r) 2.0</Name>
                      </Dictionary>
                      <WordDefinition>analyses
     See {analysis}
  </WordDefinition>
                  </Definition>
                  <Definition>
                      <Word>analyses</Word>
                      <Dictionary>
                          <Id>wn</Id>
                          <Name>WordNet (r) 2.0</Name>
                      </Dictionary>
                      <WordDefinition>analysis
 n 1: an investigation of the component parts of a whole and their
      relations in making up the whole
  </WordDefinition>
                  </Definition>
              </Definitions>
          </WordDefinition>

    'get the last WordDefinition
    Dim lastDef As XElement = doc...<WordDefinition>.LastOrDefault
```

Without the test data it will simply be:

```
    Dim doc As XElement = XElement.Load("path/URI here")

    'get the last WordDefinition
    Dim lastDef As XElement = doc...<WordDefinition>.LastOrDefault
```

Some other things you can do..

all definitions

```
    Dim allDefs As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = doc...<WordDefinition>
```

crude filter

```
    Dim whDef As String = "analys"
    Dim multiDef As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From wd In doc...<WordDefinition>
                                                  Where wd.Value.Trim.StartsWith(whDef)
                                                  Select wd
```